# Django validation of number from query string

Tags: django, validation

Im having this code to create and add students to database.
I need to make validation of count which must be integer, only positive, equal or less 100.
Please help.

```
def generate_students(request):
    count = request.GET.get('count')
    studentslist = []
    for student in range(0, int(count)):
        student = Student.objects.create(first_name = fake.first_name(), last_name = fake.last_name(), age = random.randint(18,100))
        studentslist.append(student)
    output = ', '.join(
        [f"id = {student.id} {student.first_name} {student.last_name}, age = {student.age};" for student in studentslist]
                      )
return HttpResponse(str(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is likely to work with a form, since a form has a lot of validation inplace, can clean the object, and print sensical errors.

We thus can work with a simple form:

```
from django import forms

class CountForm(forms.Form):
    count = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=100)
```

then we can validate the input with:

```
def generate_students(request):
    form = CountForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        count = form.cleaned_data['count']
        studentslist = [
            Student.objects.create(first_name = fake.first_name(), last_name = fake.last_name(), age = random.randint(18,100))
            for _ in range(count)
        ]
        output = ', '.join(
            [f'id = {student.id} {student.first_name} {student.last_name}, age = {student.age};'
             for student in studentslist]
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(str(form.errors))
    return HttpResponse(str(output))
```

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

Comment: You helped a lot. Thank you!